# Align center is not working on ie 8 and 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have develop a code for menu which is in the page center. But ie 8 and 9 it is not working. chrome and firefox working fine.

Any one please help me to fix the problem.

Html:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="hometablebg nowrap">
     <tbody><tr>
      <td align="center" valign="" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"> <ul id="topnav" style="text-align: center;   margin: auto;">
          <li id="t-home1">
          Home
          </li>

       <li id="t-report">Home</li>

               <li id="t-report">Home</li>               
            <li id="t-report">Home</li>

        </ul>


      </td>

    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
```

link:

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/9s0hq5wa/

help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this to the top of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Found that at some page in the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the 'HTML 5 Shiv'

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Put this in the `<head>` tag, usually clears up some odds and ends in IE.